# Can i add copyright and license to a web template with a license?

Tags: licensing, gpl-3

I downloaded [this template](https://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/bootstrap-templates/startup/prettydocs-free-bootstrap-theme-for-developers-and-startups/) for my website & built my website over it.
The template license says:

> This Bootstrap template is 100% FREE as long as you keep the footer attribution link. You do not have the rights to resell, sublicense or redistribute (even for free) the template on its own or as a separate attachment from any of your work.

Following this, i have not removed the footer attribution link. 
Now, i want to release my website & also open-source it on github (to host it with gh-pages).

1. Can i add copyright notice in the footer along with that attribution link, in my html pages?
2. Am i allowed to add a license (GPLv3) to my open source code ?

Comment: That is a horrible piece of crayon license. It mentions what you can't do, but does not say what you are allowed to do with the combination of the template and your work. The only safe bet is to assume nothing is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You do not have the rights to ... redistribute (even for free) the template

The right to copy the software is one of the [four freedoms](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) of free software, so that template is non-free.  Moreover, the licence is explicit that you may not sublicense the template.

As regards using the template in your website, this seems to be permissible, provided that (as you say) you maintain the prescribed footer text.  You have contributed to the website, so adding your own copyright line is definitely in order.  But when it comes to open-sourcing the work on GitHub, I don't see that you have the rights to copy the template to GitHub in the first place, and you definitely don't have the right to redistribute it under GPLv3.

I can't say how intimately tied-up in your work this template is.  If it's trivially-removable, then you can redistribute your work under GPLv3 (via GitHub, if you please) as long as you leave the template out of it, perhaps replacing it with a notice that a copy of PrettyDocs is required to make it work, and a pointer to where the user can get one.  If what you've done makes your work a derivative, in copyright terms, of PrettyDocs, then your work is all compromised, and you cannot redistribute it in this way.

If there is a useful lesson to be learned here, it may be that next time you start a work with the intent of making it free software, you should found it on *free* software, not merely *zero-cost* software.

Comment: thanks a lot, actually as i am using github pages, i cannot remove the template out, or else my page will be just some html markup. will have to find some workaround or new template for this to work, now.